# F# filter in loop

Tags: list, filter, f#

I am really new in F# language, therefore, I face an issue practically everywhere, but at this point I got completely stuck. The exercise is pretty simple to find prime numbers of given integer for example if integer is 10 the primes would be: 2,3,5,7. 
The requirement is to use lambda expressions.

Here is what I "accomplished" so far:

**Code fraction:**

```
let allNumbers  = [1..20];
let isPrime div = fun x -> x % div <> 0              

let findPrimes n = 
                   for i in 1 .. n do
                   List.filter (isPrime i) allNumbers





printfn "%A" (findPrimes 20);
```

I am keep getting an error the result of this expression is ignored of List.filter.

How it would be possible to fix that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop and `allNumbers`. Try combining them... But first, think about your `isPrime` function on its own. Does it work? It should only take one parameter. Try using `List.forall` inside it. Make sure that you are using F# Interactive (FSI) to test out individual functions. You can select lines and send them to FSI using Alt-enter in VS and VS Code. It makes F# life so much easier.

Comment: I need to somehow check if number is prime and then filter the list... But don;t know how to make it exactly..

Comment: Just get `isPrime` working first (try using List.forall) and test it with FSI.

Comment: But it returns predicate on whole list... What I would accomplish?

Comment: `isPrime` should take an `int` and return a `bool` and it should work on its own. Later on it can be passed to `List.filter` as a higher order function.

Comment: But integer should increase every time from 1 to given (n) number. Therefore, I need some kind of loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156937/discussion-between-thequickbrownfox-and-user2149578).